# Session is always empty using RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

There is the following code:

```
  describe 'Some title' do
    before do 
      session = ActionController::TestSession.new 
      session[:state] = "12334"
      get '/api/v1/menus', format: :json 
    end


    it 'some text' do
      expect(response).to be_success
      json = JSON.parse(response.body)
      puts json
    end
  end
```

Code of the controller:

```
class Api::V1::MenusController < Api::V1::ApiV1Controller

  def index
    render json: session
  end
end
```

But controller returns an empty session always. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
describe 'Some title', :type => :controller do
```

And remove `session = ActionController::TestSession.new`.

RSpec needs to know you are doing "controller things" in your test. You indicate this as above or by placing the test in *spec/controllers*.